# Insert Boolean Value through variable using Bash Script into MySql

Tags: mysql, bash

I am trying to insert a boolean value which i have stored into some variable and trying to pass it in INSERT query . I am using bash script for this purpose.

**The Script**

```
#!/bin/bash -X
#fields:  id|alias|booking_time|contact_no|deleted|grace|number_in_queue|pax|seated_time|status|walk_in_time|queue_id|user_id 

_alias="Success"
_contact_no=43456789876
_deleted="FALSE"
_number_in_queue=4
_pax=5
_status="waiting"
_queue_id=424
_user_id=550

mysql -u root -p <databasename> << EOF
INSERT INTO queue_item  VALUES ('','$_alias',now(),'$_contact_no','$_deleted',NULL,'$_number_in_queue','$_pax',now(),'$_status',now(),'$_queue_id','$_user_id');
EOF
echo "Completed"
```

I am getting some garbage value in that field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your table use boolean datatype you can just insert 1 for true or 0 for false. So your code can be

```
_deleted=0
...
INSERT INTO some_table(Boolean_Field) VALUES($_deleted)
...
```

Comment: shall i need to put the single quotes?

Comment: No need for single quotes since the value is not a string